# How to run code based on the Date\Time in the database

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm building an application for a small school. They are using a transactional model for payments.

Basically it works like this:
Student brings payment of N dollars ($500).
teacher schedules him for several classes. As soon as each class is complete (Let's say he is scheduled for classes every Monday and Friday at 11.30 - 1.30). One class cost 100 dollars, so. every Monday and Friday I want to subtract 100 the from balance.

Here's the solutions I was thinking about:
1. Create a scheduled job that will run every 10 minutes and see if any of the schedules are past due and submit a new payment.
-Hard to implement
-Possible hosting issues
2. Every time user goes to a payment page, check what have not yet been submitted.
-Not efficient?

I'm not sure what is a good way to solve this issue.

**Edit**

We do take an attendance, and here how it works right now:
We have three options Present, Absent, Absent w/excuse. So, if a student has money on the account we automatically assume that he is present. If he/she notified that he/she won't come, we make her: Absent w\excuse and do not charge her, otherwise if person is Absent but signed up for a class we still will charge  him.

Comment: I dont think this requires ascheduled job, given that you have hooks to the initiation of each transaction, i.e class. I would look at the application being aware of attendance and initiating a debit per user per class at the start/end of each class

Answer (score 2):

Well, obviously the student has to show up to the class to be charged. So someone is going to have to enter some kind of information that the student showed up for the class. 
From there it would subtract the balance for each student.

There are a number of reasons I would chose this way. First off, you have potential disputes on accounts when people say they their account is overcharged. They will want a record of what days they were charged. This is no different than kids in school that have lunch accounts. Their parents give them so much money a month to but food at school. The kids get their lunches on and the cashier goes on the computer and checks the kids account and deducts their amount for their food that day.

They have records on each day when they bought something in case of a dispute, and the transactions can be accessed by parents online. Saves a lot of legal issues. Full Automation should be avoided in case of potential bugs in code. You don't want people filing lawsuits or feeling ripped off if your system makes a single mistake. Everything should be audit ready.

Comment: I endorse @Michael Hartmann's point of view and agree with him.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Can you please take a look at my edit about attendance.

Comment: Then when you enter Present you charge them the money but annotate they were present, When Absent without excuse, charge them but annotiate it was a charge On No Show. On absent with excused, I would still record the incident as Exused with a deduction of 0. That way you have a legal record of their complete history. You have to make sure everything is accurate because there WILL be disputes and having a complete history will let your school have the information needed to justify their balances.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the first option. The second option will not have the possibility of an administrator to check the current account situations, since the accounts of the users will only change whenever the user will visit the page. I'm sure, at some point in the future, your client will add administrator features to his wish list. Then you will have to refactor your application if you have chosen option 2.